# Django ModelForm is giving me a validation error that doesn't make sense

Tags: django, modelform, django-forms

I've got a ModelForm based on a Picture.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to='instaton')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        exclude = ('pub_date','tags')
```

That's the model and the ModelForm, of course.

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if the form has been submitted
        form = PictureForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/django/instaton')
    else:
        form = PictureForm() # blank form
    return render_to_response('instaton/submit.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

That's the view (which is being correctly linked to by urls.py)

Right now, I do nothing when the form submits. I just check to make sure it's valid. If it is, I forward to the main page of the app.

```
<form action="/django/instaton/submit/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value"Submit" />
</form>
```

And there's my template (in the correct location).

When I try to actually fill out the form and just validate it, even if I do so correctly, it sends me back to the form and says "This field is required" between Name and Content. I assume it's referring to Content, but I'm not sure.

What's my problem? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the files in your form

```
form = PictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```